# Preg_match to Extract Json from Html

Tags: php

$data (HTML Response):

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
WebForm_AutoFocus('drpDwnLstLinhas');Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
$create(Artem.Google.MarkersBehavior, {"markerOptions":..EXTENSIVE JSON..,"name":"map_GoogleMarkers"}, null, null, $get("map"));
});
//]]>
</script>
...
```

I would like to extract: `{"markerOptions":..EXTENSIVE JSON..,"name":"map_GoogleMarkers"}`

Code:

```
preg_match('~$create(Artem.Google.MarkersBehavior, (.*?), null, null, $get("map"));~', $data, $json);
var_dump($json); //empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape the "$" and the "(" and ")"

```
preg_match('~\$create\(Artem.Google.MarkersBehavior, (.*), null, null, \$get\("map"\)\);~', $data, $json);
```

Tested.

Comment: just use echo $json[1];

Comment: Thanks! Working perfect!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, how about selecting my answer as the correct answer? :)